# Writing a R function with vector as in- and output in math notation?

Tags: r, notation

im struggling to write the following R function in math notation:

```
function <- function(rmm, a){
  temp <- exp(c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)**a)*c(1,rmm[1:2])
  return(temp/sum(temp))
}
```

rmm is a vector of length 2.

So far I have this:

$$f(x, y, a)  = \frac{e^{(0.5, 1.5, 2.5)*a}*(1, x, y)}{sum-from-above...}$$

Thank you.

Comment: I would begin by writing the denominator like this to avoid the minus signs: `sum\text{ }from\text{ }above}`

Comment: I don't get what you mean - there are no minus signs in the actual formula (see R code)

Comment: The R code doesn't, but the formula does. When you write "sum-from-above", LaTeX interprets the hyphens as minus signs.

Comment: yes, that's true. But I want to replace the placeholder text "sum-from-above" with some math notation signifying that the above is divided by its sum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
f(x, y, a) = \frac{1}{1*e^{0.5^a} +x*e^{1.5^a} + y*e^{2.5^a}} \left[ 1*e^{0.5^a}, x*e^{1.5^a}, y*e{2.5^a}\right]
```

which produces

[image: sample formula]

I'm not sure how you want to represent your vector in mathematical notation. There is no one right way.